# Telerik radgridview timestamp auto format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

Need your help as I am stuck at certain point in my program. 
I have a timestamp column in database which I am using to populate telerik grid view. The  default format is hh:mm:ss while data load. 
I would like to auto format user input into hh:mm:ss format. For example: in my current program when user enters 1 it auto converts it into 1.00:00:00 which is incorrect. I would would like to auto format it to 1:00:00. Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: The short version is that you need to include the relevant code and where the error is occurring - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set the column Format to Custom and then the CustomFormat property to whatever format you want.

Read more here: [GridViewDateTimeColumn](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewdatetimecolumn)